# Multiple File Provisioner in JSON Terraform

Tags: json, terraform

```
"provisioner": {
    "file": {
        "connection": {
                "private_key": "${file(\"/KeyPair.pem\")}",
                "user": "id"
        },
        "content": "${template_file.x1}",
        "destination": "/path/to/dest1"

    },

    "file": {
            "connection": {
                    "private_key": "${file(\"/KeyPair.pem\")}",
                    "user": "id"
            },
            "content": "${template_file.x2}",
            "destination": "/path/to/dest2"
    }
}
```

Here I have a JSON Terraform scriplet. I understand I will have to merge/group the file provisioners but I am not too sure how to do that

I keep getting errors whilst validating.

```
SyntaxError: Duplicate key 'file' on line 78
```

Do I have to use inline feature?

I think this may be correct. Can anyone confirm?

```
"file": {
    "connection": {
        "private_key": "${file(\"/KeyPair.pem\")}",
        "user": "id"
    },
    "content": [
        "${template_file.1}",
        "${template_file.2}"
    ],
    "destination": [
        "/path/dest/",
        "/path/dest/"
    ]
}
```

Comment: think i may worked it out?? is this correct ...?     `"file": {
 "connection": {
  "private_key": "${file(\"/KeyPair.pem\")}",
  "user": "id"
 },
 "content": [
  "${template_file.1}",
  "${template_file.2}"
 ],
 "destination": [
  "/path/dest/",
  "/path/dest/"
 ]
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please go through the official sample [here](https://www.terraform.io/docs/provisioners/connection.html)

So you should split the codes to two provisioner parts.

```
"provisioner": {
    "file": {
        "connection": {
                "private_key": "${file(\"/KeyPair.pem\")}",
                "user": "id"
        },
        "content": "${template_file.x1}",
        "destination": "/path/to/dest1"

    }
}

"provisioner": {
    "file": {
            "connection": {
                    "private_key": "${file(\"/KeyPair.pem\")}",
                    "user": "id"
            },
            "content": "${template_file.x2}",
            "destination": "/path/to/dest2"
    }
}
```

If there are a lot of files to be uploaded, provisioner `file` supports folder/directory upload.  Please go through the details

https://www.terraform.io/docs/provisioners/file.html#directory-uploads

If you got error message, please paste the detail error, otherwise, it's hard to give the suggestion.

Comment: Thanks, I have already tried that but that throws an error. I have uploaded the error in the original post. It seems in JSON syntax you cant have duplicate key. I have also gone through the official material but they don't give much information on terraform with JSON syntax hence the Q.

Comment: Are you sure you followed my answer? The error you pasted is regarding the problem you try to use two `file` in one `provisioner`. What error you got if switch to my solution?

Comment: Apologies, the error I get when I attempt your approach is  `SyntaxError: Duplicate key 'provisioner' on line 63`

Comment: Although this throws an error when using a validation tool online, terraform itself accepts duplicate keys. Thanks for your help.